# declare dynamic object with function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Usually I declare function in object like this:

```
type Obj = {
  func(): void;
}
```

But if my object is dynamic, I use:

```
type Obj = {
  [k: string]: () => void;
}
```

It seems that I can't use the same syntax, like so:

```
type Obj = {
  [k: string](): void;
}
```

How can I implement this without using an arrow function syntax?

Comment: If you want to declare that indexer returns function, you have to use function either arrow or regular:  ```type Obj = {
  [k: string]: Function
}```

Comment: Why do you want an alternative? `[k: string]: () => void;` does what you want. Note that it **doesn't** mean the result is an arrow function, just that it's a function. (It can be a method or traditional function property if you like.)

Comment: I have to admit I'm surprised `[k: string](): void;` didn't work. That's a reasonable extrapolation of TypeScript method syntax and/or JavaScript computed method syntax.

Comment: just curious why typescript does NOT allow `[k: string](): void;` syntax?

Comment: @ABOS I don't think its necessarily something that was decided. It would need to be implemented and supported, and why have an alternate syntax when the arrow syntax works just fine.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, I thought there must be something that forbids it which might cause inconsistence typing checking since it looks like something easier enough to implement from day 1. but anyway, not a big deal since we have the alternative.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir IMO the arrow function syntax should be the alternative one.

Comment: @user12499410 The arrow function signatures exist in general as types. `[k: string]: T` exists to define index signatures for any type.  `[k: string]: () => void;` follows naturally from those two.  You get the ability to define an object that when indexed returns a function basically for free, just as a consequence of other primitives you already support. `[k: string](): void` is dedicated syntax that some might intuit, others might not. This is the first time I've personally come across this suggestion. So which should be the primary and which the alternate is in the eye of the beholder...